# Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException (classpath .jasper in NetBeans)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have done project, my problem is put path or classpath of report that I make it. Sorry I am newbie around making a report. The report that I made with *iReport* has *.jrxml* extension, but *NetBeans* not read  files *.jrxml*?

So I compiled this report to a  *.jasper* and save this report to folder `src/reports/MenuProduk.jasper`.

My problem is why my *Java NetBeans* cann't read my report?

My code is:

```
public ReportViewProduk(String vName) {
    initComponents();
    dao = new ProdukDao();
    produkList= dao.getListData();

    try {
        Map m;
        m = new HashMap();
        m.put("Print By", "Sanjaya");

        jasperPrint=JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/produkReport.jasper"), 
                                    m,new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(produkList)); 
      if(PanelReport.getComponentCount()>0){
            PanelReport.removeAll();
        }   
        PanelReport.add(new  JRViewer(jasperPrint));
        PanelReport.updateUI();
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(ReportViewProduk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should put your jrxmml code in web-inf. for your code check you can povide absolute path. e.g. "path/to/your/jasperFile" in linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you jasper files are copied into "classes" dir (see the "reports" dir). I guess they are not copied there. Check NetBeans settings to include resource types *.jrxml and *.jasper to be copied when your project is compiled.